# Best way to pass reference of injected dependency in spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a Spring portlet controller class. In this class, there is a dependency like this:

```
@Autowired
protected ServiceClass someService;

@Autowired
protected ApplicationContext context;
```

From the controller, there is a utility class being called like this:

```
UtilityClass.loadStaticData((WebApplicationContext)context);
```

Inside `UtilityClass`, I have:

```
public static synchronized boolean  loadStaticData(WebApplicationContext context){

    ServiceClass someService = (ServiceClass) context.getBean("someService");
...
}
```

My question is: Is there any advantage to getting the handle of the someService in such a complicated way? We could have just passed the reference 'someService' from Controller class #1 to the UtilityClass. The author is no longer available so I am asking here.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what dependency injection tries to avoid: getting a dependency from the container instead of having the dependency injected by the container.

This utility class should be a Spring bean, where the service would be injected. And you could then inject this utility bean inside the controller.

Comment: Thanks. but what iswrong with just passign the reference around?

Comment: You could of course do that, but why bother when it can be injected in the bean directly?